# How to grant local administrator privilege for one command?

Tags: windows, security, administrator, active-directory

I'm using Windows 10 / DC Server 2012 R2 and I have some power users that needs to execute a `manage-bde` command that requires Local Administrator privilege.

Is there away that I can allow them to execute that one command without giving them the credentials for the administrator account?

---

Edit: my objective is to allow some users to encrypt usb sticks with manage-bde for some weirs use cases.
Following Narzad advice , giving the wmi "method execute" is sufficient to make the command works.

Is it possible to push the change using GPO since changing it manually on every computer is not an option ?

Comment: Which command exactly?

Comment: the command is manage-bde

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1127182/unlock-bitlocked-data-drive-as-standard-user-on-the-command-line  2nd answer, Give that a shot

Comment: Maybe you could also explain what you want to do exactly. For some scenario's you could for instance set up a scheduled task that runs elevated.

Comment: why not try to configure a logon script through GPO, it will run on user side without giving local admin right separately

Answer (score 0):

I take it that you wish to enable users to run one specific application as
administrator without entering the password.

**Run As GUI**

The Technet program
[Run As GUI](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Run-As-GUI-b23012b2#content)
might be one solution (if it still works on Windows 10).
It keeps the entered data safe in encrypted format.
Pushing it to all users might require finding where it keeps that encrypted
file, and distributing it together with the program.

[image]

**Task Scheduler**

Another solution might be to use the Task Scheduler to schedule running this
application as administrator, but with a trigger that is never activated,
and allow users to run it manually with the command :

```
schtasks /run /tn "task-name"
```

For more information see the article
[Windows 7: Elevated Program Shortcut without UAC Prompt - Create](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/11949-elevated-program-shortcut-without-uac-prompt-create.html).